# How to fit the Image to the size of a CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a cardview which has an ImageView inside it. I use it in a RecylerView with a GridLayout. I want the Image to scale to the whole size of the CardView. At the moment the Grid of the Cards looks good, however, there is a white background around each item (see Screenshot).
[image]

If I set the background to transparent the white background disappears, but unfortunately now the margins between each cards are too big and I can't control them (see Screenshot).
[image]

Here is the XML code of the cardview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="2dp" />



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Is there a way how I can have full Images while having small margins between the cards without a white background? I do not necessarily have to use a CardView. I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

Update: As demanded here is the XML layout file of the Fragment, in which the RecyclerView (with CardView) is embedded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
            android:layout_width="432dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:background="#435cb53f"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_ToolBar_CocktailSelectionActivity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="Softdrinks" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylerViewMenuItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity" />





        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding this to the ImageView  android:adjustViewBounds="true".

Comment: @LaurentiuDaniel Agreed. You'll also probably want to experiment with the `android:scaleType` attribute.

Comment: Add a Linear Layout with height and width matching parent as a child to cardview and set image view inside it with height and width matching the parent. This adds rounded corner to a images as well, you need to use scaleType to center crop.

Comment: Thanks Laruentiu for your comment. I added what you said but it did not change anything (with and without the transparent color).

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your comment. I tried the "android:scaleType = "FIT_CENTER" attribute but it can't find the FIT_CENTER or to any other constants of ImageView mentioned here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Comment: You should be able to set the background to transparent and then add `android:paddingTop` to the CardView. You might also want to try using `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` instead, and perhaps get rid of `app:cardUseCompatPadding` too. Ultimately, you'l just have to fiddle with these various things until they suit you. For reference, here's what mine looks like from a recent app: https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/grid_list_item.xml

Comment: @VanessaF In XML you would type `fitCenter`. Also if you leave it blank and put your cursor between the quotes, you can type Ctrl + spacebar to see a list of all the possible values: https://i.imgur.com/Hw6a96m.png

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your answers and effort. I used the 'fitCenter' (and also tried it without it). I also used different values for the paddingTop (0 dp, 50 dp, 200 dp). None of them seems to have any effect on the layout. The problem still persists.

Comment: Maybe something with my posted XML layout file for the CardView is wrong. Would someone mind having a look at it again?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Do you have any further ideas? I would really appreciate any new idea. Did not think that it was going to be so difficult to use an Image with a CardView.

Comment: Thanks Gouse Mohiddin for your answer. I tried your approach and basically it works. However, there is one downside. In the layouteditor I can't see anything about the design as the CardView is only very small. Nonetheless thanks you very much for the comment. It helped a lot.